# Get part of a string with a dynamic lookahead

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
[TITLE|suffix=ta|prefix=tb] [STORENAME|suffix=sa|prefix=sb] [DYNAMIC|limit=10|prefix=a|random=0|suffix=b|reverse=0]
```

And I am trying to get value of the *prefix* of *DYNAMIC*, which is **a**. The looking should start with `[DYNAMIC` and end with either `|` or `]`. Everything between `[DYNAMIC` and `prefix=` is dynamic.

This is what I have tried so far: `(?=DYNAMIC\\|)(prefix=)([^\||\]]+)`

Comment: `s.match(/(?<=\[DYNAMIC[^\][]*?\|prefix=)[^|\]]+/g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use either of the two expressions:

```
(?<=\[DYNAMIC\b[^\][]*?\|prefix=)[^|\]]+
\[DYNAMIC\b[^\][]*?\|prefix=([^|\]]+)
```

***NOTE**: If the value can be empty, replace `+` with `*` after `[^|\]]`*.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/purxaB/1) (the result is the match value) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/purxaB/2) (access Group 1 value upon a match).

The point here is that `[^\][]*?` will not let the regex engine overflow the square brackets and if there is a `[DYNAMIC...]` string without `|prefix=` in it, there will be no match in the subsequent square bracket string that will contain `|prefix=`.

**Details**

- `(?<=...)` - a positive lookbehind that requires its pattern to match immediately to the left of the current position
- `\[DYNAMIC` - `[DYNAMIC` string
- `\b` - word boundary
- `[^\][]*?` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`, as few as possible
- `\|prefix=` - a `|prefix=` string
- `([^|\]]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `|` and `]`.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be:

```
\[DYNAMIC.*?\|prefix=([^|\]]*)
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/MrcAdR/2)

---

- `\[DYNAMIC` - Match opening bracket and `DYNAMIC` literally.
- `.*?` - Lazy match up to:
- `\|prefix` - Match pipe symbol and `prefix=` literally.
- `(` - Open 1st capture group.

  - `[^|\]]*` - Match any character other than pipe symbol and closing bracket as many as possible.
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group.